# SQL Server 2008 FOR INSERT trigger not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am studying the trigger and I got a question.

I am creating a trigger to change the time complex.

In the data table `weeklymeeting`

```
|section_id| meeting type| days| timestart|timeend|class_id|
| 13       | Lecture     |   5 | 01:00:00 |02:00:00|12     |
```

`timestart` and `timeend` are of datatype `TIME`

I am creating the trigger that checking the time complex

for example

if user uses query like

```
INSERT INTO DBO.WeeklyMeetings VALUES (35, 1,1 ,'11:40:00','11:42:00', 42)
```

it should insert the data

however

```
INSERT INTO CSE132B.DBO.WeeklyMeetings VALUES (35, 1, 1, '12:30:00','01:30:00', 42)
```

then it must return error message because it is time complex

Therefore I created a trigger to check the time complex..but such as

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[check_section_time_complex] ON [dbo].[WeeklyMeetings]
FOR INSERT AS
IF EXISTS(select * from inserted as i INNER JOIN dbo.WeeklyMeetings as m  ON (i.timestart BETWEEN m.timestart and m.timeend)  
OR( i.timeend BETWEEN m.timestart and m.timeend ))
begin
 RAISERROR ('Can not update data because  section time is complexing with other section!!', 16,1);
rollback tran
end
```

however,  it is not really working...i am not really sure that reason....

does anyone knows problems in this trigger ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "it's not really working" you mean that it's allowing conflicting data to be inserted and then raising an error, this is because you've specified a `FOR INSERT` trigger which means that it's happening *after* the data is inserted.

If you want to prevent the data being inserted you'll need to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger which happens *before* insert and within that do the insert yourself if it is valid.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx for the trigger definition.

If the error is something else please describe it more fully.

Comment: i changed to instead of and then error message is working fine. it has to insert this data if there is no problem but it is not inserting anydata now...

Comment: In an INSTEAD OF trigger you then have to do valid data insertion yourself. An INSTEAD OF trigger *replaces* any attempted insertion so if after checks you want to insert the row you need to do it in the trigger explicitly. Beware of ending up in a recursive loop of inserts.

Comment: Your other (slightly ugly) option would be to stick with the FOR INSERT (AFTER) trigger and if the data is invalid, delete it despite it having just been created

Comment: lol. i just used else case to insert data to the table!! thanks!!! I think , i was misunderstanding about concept of "instead of" and "for" lol

Comment: @DcRedwing - if you are going to write this as a trigger, make sure you write it to cope with edge cases - e.g. if a single `INSERT` statement actually attempts to insert two rows which overlap each other.